# Boolean algebra plus cartesian product

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the standard name for an algebraic system that has the following operations and axioms:
1. Boolean algebra structure
2. a product that behaves like a cartesian product
I am thinking here of a collection of sets that is a Boolean algebra and is closed under cartesian product. 
Thanks, jlouis
P.S.: In general, I an looking for the standard names of algebraic systems that are of use when one wants to study  a collection of sets that is a boolean algebra and that may be closed under cartesian product, or under a power set like operation, ....

Answer (score 0):

It is a kind of [Boolean algebra with *operators*](http://math.chapman.edu/cgi-bin/structures.pl?Boolean_algebras_with_operators), with a specific binary operation, the cartesian product, which is indeed additive w.r.t. union ($(A\cup B)\times C=(A\times C) \cup( B\times C)$).

Perhaps you might also be interested in *categories with cartesian products* or *cartesian closed categories*.